# Why do pages flicker in JSF 1.1 with struts for template

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF 1.1 with struts. Pages flicker while navigation. Is there any solution for that. I used the below code to avoid

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="BlendTrans(Duration=.01)" />
<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="BlendTrans(Duration=.01)" />
```

is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the so-called "Fajax" (Fake Ajax) technique. This is indeed supposed to avoid "flash of content" during postbacks in MSIE. I only can't tell from experience since I never used/tried/tested them.

The pages will flicker in MSIE if there's a long gap between the first bit and the last bit of the HTTP response and also when the stylesheets and background images are not cached by the client side.